# Need Xcopy command to copy and rename all the files

Tags: command-line, xcopy

I need a 'Xcopy' or any copy command to copy a file from source to destination and rename the file.

for example

Source directory : C:\Source\

Files in Sourced irectory : textfile.txt ; xmlfile.xml; htmlfile.htm

Destination directory : C:\Destination\

Files in Destination directory: textfile.txt.abc ; xmlfile.xml.abc; htmlfile.htm.abc

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that you are using Windows Vista/7 or so,

```
copy C:\Source\*.* C:\Destination\*.*.tmp
```

The Destination folder has to exist, otherwise the copy will fail. It will not do the copy recursively, but in your example it works perfectly!

Comment: thanks for reply.. if i need to copy recursively is there an option?

Comment: It is getting much more complex then. It is not possible to copy recursively with the copy command only. xcopy can copy recursively but not rename as far as i know

Answer (score -1):

Use the xcopy command.

Specify your source as a folder (backslash on the end) and the command will operate recursively with the switch `/E`

```
xcopy "c:\source\" "c:\destination\" /E
```

The folder contents will be recursively copied to "c:\destination\"

Finally, use the `ren` command to rename your folder:

```
ren "c:\source\destination" "copiedfolder"
```

Your finished batch file will look like:

```
xcopy "c:\source\" "c:\destination\" /E
ren "c:\source\destination" "copiedfolder"
```

As stated in another answer, the destination folder has to exist. If it does not, consider the mkdir command!

As a note, try entering xcopy /? for extended help on the command. /? works with many standard windows commands.